# How to combine ReactJs Router Link and material-ui components (like a button)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, client-side, material-ui

I need to find a solution to be able to combine together the  functionality of react router with the material ui components.

For instance, I've this scenario: a router  and a  button. What I tried to do it is to mix them together, and restyle them.

So from a simple link

```
<Link className={this.getClass(this.props.type)} to={`${url}`} title={name}>{name}</Link>
```

I tried to create a material ui button as the following

```
<Link className={this.getClass(this.props.type)} to={`${url}`} title={name}>
  <FlatButton label={name} />
</Link>
```

but I have the following error and Javascript breaks

> invariant.js?4599:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105).

Do you have any idea how to manage this situation?
Thank you in advance and if you need more information let me know

Comment: I have come across this problem and with material-ui, using Link sometimes breaks the style you should you react router's browserHistory and push the url manually

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The way to do in new versions is:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// ... some code

render(){
    return (
        <Button component={Link} to={'/my_route'}>My button</Button>
    );
}
```

Look at this [thread](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7186#issuecomment-523629450) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585373/integrates-react-route-links-into-material-ui-list)

Comment: The important note is to **import `Link` from `react-router-dom`, NOT from  material-ui library**. That was my mistake!

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
<FlatButton label="Details" 
            containerElement={<Link to="/coder-details" />} 
            linkButton={true} />
```

See https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/850

Comment: Works great! But how do we disable the redirect when the button is disabled?

Comment: in v1 this is now `component={props => <Link to="/coder-details" {...props}/>}`

Comment: Solution provided by @cyberwombat works great but it has caveats. You can read more here:
https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-inlining

Answer (score 6):

```
<Button
          size="large"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => {}}
          variant="outlined"
          component={RouterLink}
          to={{
            pathname: `enter your path name`,
          }}
        >
          Click Here
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way when using typescript:

```
import { NavLink as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Button,
  Collapse,
  ListItem,
  makeStyles,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";

type NavItemProps = {
  className?: string;
  depth: number;
  href?: string;
  icon?: any;
  info?: any;
  open?: boolean;
  title: string;
};

const NavItem: React.SFC<NavItemProps> = ({

const CustomLink = React.forwardRef((props: any, ref: any) => (
    <NavLink
      {...props}
      style={style}
      to={href}
      exact
      ref={ref}
      activeClassName={classes.active}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <ListItem
      className={clsx(classes.buttonLeaf, `depth-${depth}`)}
      disableGutters
      style={style}
      key={title}
      button
      component={CustomLink}
      {...rest}
    >
      <ListItemIcon>
        {Icon && <Icon className={classes.icon} size="20" />}
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={title} className={classes.title} />
    </ListItem>
  );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Material UI button as React Router link
To use as a React Router Link, you can use the component prop of the Button.

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button component={Link} to="/posts">
        Posts
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no component prop on MUI Button, so I made that

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
        <Button
          type="button"
          variant="text"
          onClick={() => navigate(Routes.yourPath)}
        >
          Hello
        </Button>
```

Comment: Yes there is.. what is your MUI version ?