# Integrates react-route Links into Material UI list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im trying to create a [list of links](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/) in a sidebar. The problems is that if I use

```
<ListItem button component='a' href="/persons">
```

The page reloads instead of going to the url like a [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component would do.

```
<Link to='/persons' >
```

I wonder, how can I replace the Material UI listItem href behaviour with the react-router Link behaviour? This is the list im trying to fix:

```
// this breaks the design
<Link to='/persons' >
    <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
            <Icon>people</Icon>
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Personas" />
    </ListItem>
</Link>

// this reloads the page, i want to avoid
<ListItem button component='a' href="/persons">
    <ListItemIcon>
        <Icon>bar_chart</Icon>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Reports" />
</ListItem>
```

This is how the link looks:

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `Link` as the component of the `ListItem` and use it as the following

```
<List>
  <ListItem component={Link} to="/reports">
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Icon>bar_chart</Icon>
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Reports" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Answer (score 6):

For a `<ListItem />` The `component` prop can be a `string` (for a dom element) or a `react component` itself.

https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/

You can define any component

```
const ListItemComponent  =  () => {
  return <Link to="/test">Check</Link>
}
```

as pass it as a `component` prop to `<ListItem />`.

```
        <List>
          <ListItem component={ListItemComponent}>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
```

Try this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogpmxx